# rss feed code help

Tags: plugins, rss

this rss feed question was resolved but now when i tried this code `<a href="<?php echo get_post_comments_feed_link($feed); ?>">RSS feed of this post</a>` on my archives page,then i am getting the wrong url feed
what i want is when i click on the this feed, then i should get all the feeds of that current page which means, my url is this `http://mbas.in/location/mba-in-ghana` where location is my custom taxonomy, if i write this in url `http://mbas.in/location/mba-in-ghana/feed` then i get all the feeds of that page,
but if i write the code and i click on the link then it is giving me feeds of this url
`http://mbas.in/university-ghana-business-school/emba/feed` this is the first post of my that page,

what is the problem with this?

Comment: Lost me on so many levels. What's up with overwriting old question with new one? What **post comments feed** has to do **custom taxonomies**?? I gave you links both to get_post_comments_feed_link() and feeds in general, had you even tried to go through those?

Comment: i just want a link above my archives page, where if i click on that link then it should redirect me to the feeds of that page,

i tried the code `<a href="<?php echo get_post_comments_feed_link($feed); ?>">RSS feed of this post</a>` 
but it is giving me wrong url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<del>Not entirely sure. This is template tag and should be used in Loop, but for single post page it works fine most of the time even outside of Loop. Seems to from quick test.</del>

Disregard that. The issue is you were forgetting to `echo` it. :)

Also there is specialized template tag for comment feeds: [`get_post_comments_feed_link()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_comments_feed_link).

> and is there any plugin where as soon as i publish a new post, automatically the rss feed is also created of it???

Not sure what you mean here. When post is published it automatically appears in main site's feed.

Comment: hey thanks `get_post_comments_feed_link()` worked, and i am looking for a plugin, where if i publish a new post, automatically it should also post in feed

Comment: @ntechi still not sure... do you want something different from [native feed options](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Feeds#Finding_Your_Feed_URL)?